# Jmeter is skipping http request under thread Group but some time its sending http request

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

I created one project in JMeter and added one thread group

This thread group is having 2-3 HTTP request files

While sending load test, it's executing 1st HTTP request but other HTTP is not sending.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 3):

You've marked [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) Success **only** option,

This means that the 2 HTTP Requests probably failed and therefore aren't display.

Uncheck the Success checkbox to see all the requests

Comment: Thank you for ur suggestion.